# How to salt and hash a password

Tags: vb.net, t-sql, security, hash, salt

The code below allows a user to enter user name and password to log in to enter marks of students. SQL data reader verifies the user credentials from the database before authentication takes place. I would be grateful if someone could modify the code by salting and hashing the password.

```
Dim frm As New MarksEntryFrm
    Dim flag As Boolean
    flag = False
    If cboForm.Text = "" Or cboAcadYear.Text = "" Or cboSubjCode.Text = "" Or txtUserName.Text = "" Or txtPassword.Text = "" Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please any of the fields cannot be left blank", "Blank fields", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    Else
        cmd = New SqlCommand("Select a.Form,a.AcademicYear,b.SubjectID,b.UserID,b.Password,c.Term from StudentDetails.Programmes a, StudentDetails.Subjects b,RegistrationDetails.Registration c where b.SubjectID='" & cboSubjCode.SelectedItem & "' and b.UserID='" & txtUserName.Text & "' and b.Password='" & txtPassword.Text & "' collate Latin1_General_CS_AS", cn)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserID", txtUserName.Text) 'protects the database from SQL Injection
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", txtPassword.Text) 'protects the database from SQL Injection

        dr1 = cmd.ExecuteReader
        ctr = ctr + 1
        If dr1.Read Then
            frm.Show()
            ctr = 0
            Hide()
        ElseIf ctr < 3 Then
            MessageBox.Show("Incorrect Subject Code,User Name or Password. Please try again.", "Wrong data entered", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Asterisk)
        Else
            MsgBox("Unathorized access. Aborting...")
            Close()
        End If
        dr1.Close()
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Hashing has nothing to do with SQL injection.  You need to learn how to _properly_ use parameters.  (you also need to hash and salt)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

P.S. Akaglo, a better way to check if any fields were left empty is to use the String.IsNullOrEmpty() method. Your method will not detect any null or space characters.

Comment: Please show me specifically how I should use the String.IsNullOrEmpty() method in my code. I'd be grateful if you could if you could very kindly do that for me.

Comment: If String.IsNullOrEmpty(strName) Then
Messagebox.Show("String is empty")

Comment: Oh please, I'm very eager to use your suggestion, but I still can't see how to go about it in my coding. Kindly edit my code in conformity to your suggestion. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Use a parametrized query

```
    Dim cmdText As String = _
                    "INSERT INTO Customer(UserName, [Password]) VALUES (@UserName,@Password)"
    Dim cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(cmdText, con)
    With cmd.Parameters
        .Add(New SqlParameter("@UserName", txtUserName.Text))
        .Add(New SqlParameter("@Password", txtPassword.Text))
    End With
```

Answer (score 0):

In the .NET membership providers you will get hashing and seeding given by the .NET library which should be implemented correctly. This IMHO is much to prefer for rolling your own solution. There is an [introduction to membership here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh26yfzy.aspx)

IF you prefer to make your implementation the seeding and hashing part is not overtly complex. The seeding could be as simple as adding a random string to the original password prior to hashing it. You then store the hash and the seed in the database. When the user provides the password you then simply readd the seed and compare the hashes. Note that when you make random strings for cryptographic purposes you should not rely on `Random`, but rather go for some  [cryptographically secure random generator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rngcryptoserviceprovider.aspx). The `System.Security.Cryptography` also contains implementations of many suitable hashing algorithms (sha1, sha256 or similar).

Again: In my opinion you should go for a solution using the `SqlMembershipProvider` to avoid reimplementing security critical stuff.

Comment: Could you elaborate more on *SqlMembershipProvider* and maybe know an article that goes a little further on that direction?

Comment: The SqlMembershipProvider is just a concretization of the membership provider using MS SQL as user store. It is quite flexible and seems to provide the functionality needed. Membership is a large topic, but msdn provides info http://bit.ly/sF9Ic8. To get more information about membership I think a separate question would be appropriate.